# Unpacking Parameter Pack in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, future, argument-unpacking

I have two functions `f` and `g`. `f` calculates it's return value asynchronously and returns a future. Now, based on several return values of `f`, I want to call `g`, but I want to make sure that the computations of the values of `f` happen in parallel.

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
std::future<T> f(T& t);

template <typename... T>
void g(T&&... t)

template <typename... T>
void call_wrapper(T&&... t) {
  auto f1 = f(t1); // How do I set the values of f1... fn
  auto f2 = f(t2);
  ...
  g(f1.get(), f2.get()....); // How do I call g
}
```

How can I unpack the types from the variadic template `T` of the `call_wrapper` function?

Comment: Have a look at `std::tuple`. It's perfect for storing variadic pack objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edit2: I guess i misunderstood the question, i forgot subzero wanted to return `std::future`s and simply thought that the only problem was the parameter pack syntax.
Hopefully, using an helper function as in my first edit should work though]

<s>You can simply do:</s>

```
template <typename... T>
void call_wrapper(T&&... t) {
  g(f(std::forward<T>(t)).get()...);
}
```

Unless i misunderstood what you want to do.

Edit1: if you want to do something else, you can divide the function in two calls, like this:

```
template<typename... T>
void helper(T&&... t) {
  // ...
  g(std::forward<T>(t).get()...);
}

template <typename... T>
void call_wrapper(T&&... t) {
  helper(f(std::forward<T>(t))...);
}
```

Comment: That should work, as in it will compute the right value, but the computations of `f` won't happen in parallel. The first argument will be calculated, then the second and so on.

Comment: that could work... making the `future`s in one function and calling the `get()`s in another

Comment: Ah, i forgot about "in parallel", sorry, maybe the second form would work then, but i'm not sure, i'll edit to state that i misunderstood a part of your question.

Comment: Leveraging the fact that all arguments are evaluated before the call. Neat !

Comment: Your example doesn't compile. `t` isn't expanded in `helper`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick solution storing the `std::future`s in a `std::tuple` :

```
template <class T, std::size_t... Idx>
void callG(T &tuple, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    g(std::get<Idx>(tuple).get()...);
}

template <typename... T>
void call_wrapper(T&&... t) {
    auto results = std::make_tuple(f(std::forward<T>(t))...);
    callG(results, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36d4e90069f8549b)